# React Native Async Storage resolve

Tags: react-native, axios, es6-promise, asyncstorage

I am trying to access a rest api endpoint that requires you send it a token with react native. For development purposes am storing it in Async Storage wrapped in a APIToken class with two methods that set or get the token and returns the token.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

class APIToken {
    constructor(){}
    async get(){
        try {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('api_token');
            if (token !== null) {
              // We have data!!
              console.log(token);
              return token
            }
          } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
          }
          //return null
    }
    async set(token){
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('api_token', token);
            return token
          } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
          }
          //return null
    }
}

export default APIToken
```

So I am using the async functions in hopes that I can resolve the key to a string value instead of a promise. When I call the api using these functions I get the key returning correctly in the console but in the headers it returns as a promise.

```
const key = function() {
    const k = (new APIToken()).get()
    return k
  }


const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: Config.API_URL_V1,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key(),
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
  });
```

What is returned from the console from the ApiToken class

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9uZXQtYXBwMS5oZXJva3VhcHAuY29tXC9hcGlcL3YxXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU2NDkzMTcxMywiZXhwIjoxNTY0OTM1MzEzLCJuYmYiOjE1NjQ5MzE3MTMsImp0aSI6InpUMzV5NU43Q2NGejRTanciLCJzdWIiOiI1ZDMzNTcwNDgwMmRmMDAwMDc2YmFkOTciLCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIn0.nhDmwYWS5NaGifg-atwEw4DwUNvvpv-I_Ntw5L9kmCc
```

The Authorization header in the call:

```
Authorization: "Bearer [object Object]"
```

I have tried so many different thing and have been unable to get the key so I can use it in my api calls without getting 403 due to the key no returning correctly. Any help would be great.

Comment: Priced? I don't think I know what you mean.

Comment: Is there any value in an object that you want?

Comment: [object Object]"

Comment: I am trying to get the api token from async storage like in the get function

Comment: Did you try JSON.stringify(key())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong in key function and api function when call key you don't use await and in key when call get token you don't use await too. You need convert both function to async or using promise then. Below code will solve you problem. Please try it.

```
const key = async function () {
    const apiToken = new APIToken();
    const k = await apiToken.get();
    return k;
}


const api = async function () {
    var token = await key();
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: Config.API_URL_V1,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
    });
}

async function fetchEvents() {
    let request = await api();
    return request.get(Config.API_URL_V1 + 'events').catch((error) => console.log(error.response))
}
```

Comment: I get api.get is not a function. When I call this function function fetchEvents() {
    return api.get(Config.API_URL_V1+'events')
    .catch( (error) => console.log(error.response))
}

Comment: try the new code. when we handle async function. sometimes think become more complicated because it have chain effect to the caller.

Comment: Yes that works you saved me hours of time. Is async await the best way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: It's depend on what you need. Async Await or Promise Then is same just different format and which one more readable for you. Please use it with caution. Don't treat async as sync. It can be fatal bug in production. :)